# Searching for £ sign with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm struggling with encodings and lxml. I'm reading in some html from a website and would like to search for a tag that includes a £ in its text using lxml. I can search the the tag(h3) and get the contents to print fine but if I try to search for the £ sign within the text I get a UnicodeDecodeError. I need to do the latter because it's a more general case.

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

# prints #£13,999
print tree.cssselect('h3')[0].text_content().encode("utf-8")

# generates "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

# prints £13,999
print tree.cssselect('h3:contains(u"\xa3")')[0].text_content().encode('utf-8')
```

Any hep you can provide would be much appreciated... I've tried a several different things and this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Please post a snippet of `html`, containing an `h3` tag and the `£` sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not experienced with neither python nor lxml, but the problem could be that the 'h3' string isn't a unicode string *and* that the byte `a3` isn't a unicode code point by itself. You could try to replace:

```
'h3:contains(u"\xa3")'
```

with:

```
u'h3:contains("\u00a3")'
```